# Create figure using function javaScript function createElement(tagName)

Tags: javascript, html, web

I need to create a new figure at runtime on my web app. I am using javascript and html/css.
The element that i got to create is the follow:

```
<figure id = "myImage" class="ball" >
    <span class="shadow">
    </span>
</figure>
```

I have tried some tag names and the "ball" isn't created. 
The following code is an example(not working) what is the problem?

```
var generatedBall = document.createElement("FIGURE");
generatedBall.class = 'ball';
generatedBall.style.background = 'yellow';
document.body.appendChild(generatedBall);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is it just adding the ball class that is not working for you? `generatedBall.className = generatedBall.className + " ball";`

Comment: I put this code into a fiddle, and the figure is definitely appearing in the DOM. What's the issue?

Comment: @JonathanBrooks can you give me the fiddle link? With this code isn't working on my program.

Comment: @AndréAlves See my answer, fiddle is linked there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Element` does not have a `class` property. Instead, you can add and remove classes using `classList`. So your example would become:

```
var generatedBall = document.createElement('figure');
generatedBall.classList.add('ball');
generatedBall.style.background = 'yellow';
document.body.appendChild(generatedBall);
```

Comment: Thanks, I just copy past your code and is working well :D

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me, see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggcdw9e8/3/).

You just have to give it height;

```
var generatedBall = document.createElement("figure");
generatedBall.classList.add('ball'); //Edited this 
generatedBall.style.background = 'yellow';
generatedBall.style.height = '100px'; //Added bit
document.body.appendChild(generatedBall);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, my code line 'generatedBall.class = 'ball';' was wrong. Indeed the height is need but i got it on CSS.

Answer (score 1):

See the exact output on this page [See Here](http://goo.gl/qPoJiA)

```js
var innerSpan = document.createElement('span');
innerSpan.classList.add('shadow');
var generatedBall = document.createElement('figure');
generatedBall.setAttribute("id","myImage")
generatedBall.classList.add('ball');
document.body.appendChild(generatedBall);
generatedBall.appendChild(innerSpan);
```